# Gradle Project Sync Failed: Peer not authenticated

Tags: android, gradle

I'm getting the following error when trying to sync my Gradle project:

```
Gradle 'android_studio' project refresh failed
    Error: Cause: peer not authenticated
```

Here's my project's build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what the problem is, I tried changing my gradle path to 2.1.0, but that did nothing. Any ideas? I seem to get this damn error every time I open Android Studio...

Comment: For the latest android studio you'll need ```classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'```.

Comment: I've tried changing it to 2.1.0 but it still gives the same error to me.

Answer (score 0):

Open your /gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties file

replace 'https' with 'http' in the distributionUrl:

example `distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip`

and also be sure to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'` to do this

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately I'm still seeing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who may run into this issue in the future and find almost no one knows what's going on, here's the very subtle thing that was happening for me.

I had Charles proxy running in the background, set to only record for endpoints I wanted it to record for. This was causing it to block the traffic from Gradle when it was downloading wahtever it is Gradle downloads, which gave me the 'peer not authenticated' error. I eventually found this by looking in the logs and seeing a whole mess of SSL errors.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occur due to internet connections!  Check your connection and sync again (rebuild project)